# Access Control on sub report on form

Tags: ms-access

I'm trying to reference a control on a sub-report which is located on a form. I've done this before using subforms on a form but the subreport version is giving me an error:

```
[Forms]![FormName]![SubreportName].[Form]![ControlName]
```

It always returns #Error. Even when there is data  in the control. Any ideas?

All of the below throw an exception:

```
[Reports]![FormName]![SubreportName].[Form]![ControlName]
[Forms]![FormName]![SubreportName].[Report]![ControlName]
[Reports]![FormName]![SubreportName].[Report]![ControlName]
```

Answer (score 1):

A subreport is located in a report, not in a form. Thus:

```
[Reports]![ReportName]![SubreportName].Report![ControlName]
```